# Django Rest Framework связи ManyToMany

Tags: django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Как добавить данные в связь пробую делать так.

```
def create (self, validated_data)
    create_rig = Rig.objects.create(**validated_data)
    abs_user = AbsUser.objects.get(uid = pk)
    abs_user.rig = Rig.objects.filter(id = create_rig.id)
    abs_user.save()
```

Происходит следующее все связанные записи rig удаляются а записывается только одна. Как реализовать добавление связанных записей?

Answer (score 0):

Дело втом что вы переприсваеваете связь rig а не добавляете новую.
Попробуйте вызвать метод add на rig

```
create_rig = Rig.objects.create(**validated_data)
    abs_user = AbsUser.objects.get(uid = pk)
    abs_user.rig.add(Rig.objects.filter(id = create_rig.id))
    abs_user.save()
```